# The parameterized constructors of the java.util.Date class are deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: java, date, deprecated

What can I use to replace this, `new Date(2009, 12, 9)`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And for good reason, if you want December 12th, 2009, you need `new Date(109, 11, 9)`.

Comment: @Yishai: I dispute that the reasons are "good".

Comment: @Yishai: That seems to be more of an arbitrary obfuscation than helpful.

Comment: It surprises me how trivial questions like this which are already answered in API docs (and asked countless times in SO before) get quickly upvoted while tough and more interesting questions doesn't get much votes.

Comment: @Jon, so much for being friendly to C programmers...

Comment: @BalusC, perhaps the tough and more interesting questions are not being asked in a way that leads people to want to view them?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Copying the mistakes of another API doesn't count as a good reason, IMO :)

Comment: Better idea would be to look at the java docs first. Any core class like that will have an explanation what to use instead of the deprecated method.
A handy trick if using Eclipse is to click the deprecated method, hold down 'Shift' and press 'F2' this will open the method in the java docs in your browser. You might need to set up the java docs url first.

Comment: The constructor was deprecated because it works unreliably across time zones, which on one hand I consider a good reason, on the other hand not very relevant anymore since no one should want to use the `Date` class at all any longer. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash below,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note: this answer was written in 2009. Since then, `java.time` has become the preferred date/time API in Java.

---

Ideally, use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead. It's an infinitely superior API to the built-in one. You'd then want to choose between [`LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) depending on your exact requirements (it's a complicated area - I'm not going to try to summarise in a sentence or two, but the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) do a good job).

If absolutely necessary, use a [java.util.Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and convert that to a `Date` when you need to.

Comment: +1 for Joda Time, it's a dream compared with Date and Calendar.

Comment: That could have been great, but i'm using gxt (google web toolkit and ext js), so I think I have to use a date object with this API.

Comment: @Tim: It's *always* worth mentioning non-standard environments in the question...

Answer (score 25):

[Calendar !](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2009, Calendar.DECEMBER, 12);
```

Notice that i didn't put 12 for december because it's actually 11 (january is 0).

Then, you can add or remove seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or year easily with :

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -5);
```

And finally, if you want a Date :

```
cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Note that with this solution, hours, minutes, seconds (and fractions) are set to their current value. This is not really clean.

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) it points you towards using [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by  Calendar.set(year + 1900, month,
> date, hrs, min) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs,
> min).

If you look at the `Date` constructor params you'll see why it was deprecated:

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> year - the year minus 1900.
> month - the month between 0-11.
> date - the day of the month between 1-31.
> hrs - the hours between 0-23.
> min - the minutes between 0-59.
> ```

`year` isn't what you expect and neither is `month`.

To represent the date you have mentioned you need to call `Date` like this **(not recommended)**

```
new Date(2009-1900, 12-1, 9)
```

The alternative using `Calendar` is

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2009, 11, 9); //year is as expected, month is zero based, date is as expected
Date dt = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Calendar's month is still zero based.

Comment: actually, month is what I'd expect.  It's date that drive me nuts.  Everything in Java is zero based, except the date!

Comment: @BlausC: So it is. No wonder people prefer to use Joda date time instead of this poor Calendar API.

Comment: Update: These terrible date-time classes have been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See the modern solution in [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842678/642706).

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;


public class DateTest {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MM, dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse("2009, 12, 9");
        System.out.println( date );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be careful not to make the `SimpleDateFormat` a `static` instance as it is not thread safe. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09263.html

Comment: :-o I didn't knew it was not thread safe. Fortunately most of the times I have used it ( although declared as class member ) was in a thread safe context :)

Comment: Use the *java.time* classes for thread-safety and many other benefits. See the modern solution in [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842678/642706).

Answer (score 4):

Tim, in your comments you mentioned that you are doing this in a GXT context - i.e. in GWT client code. GWT does not support GregorianCalendar and you will most likely not be able to put JodaTime through the GWTCompiler (you may be able to, but do you really want to).

I think you are left really with the option to using JNSI if you want to do calendar operations in GWT. See the Date class in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.of(2009, 12, 9).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2009-12-09T00:00Z[Etc/GMT]
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ipHhtU)

Like `java.util.Date`, an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc), but unlike `java.util.Date`, which does not represent a real Date-Time object (a `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`), it represents a real Date-Time object.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: To replace `new Date(...)`, you'd need to tack on a `.getTime()`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately date support in Java is completely awful. Officially, you'd probably have to do this with Calendar, but that shouldn't be necessary in my opinion. Like others have mentioned, Joda time is a lot better, but still not quite as easy to use as dates in Ruby on Rails.

I'm not aware of any Java package that gives you quite that amount of date support (Joda falls short a bit, but comes close), but in Groovy, using TimeCategory gives you very Ruby on Rails-like date support.

Comment: Much has changed since this post, with the arrival of the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later. See the modern solution in [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842678/642706).